# Keep runnable state in Threadpool

Tags: java, jaxb

There is any way to create a runnable task, that keep state, and can be used for several threads as `ThreadLocal` in a `Threadpool`.

I have the case where I have a `DocumentBuilder` that is not Thread-safe, and I would like to reuse for at least 10 threads, and `.reset` every time I finish in each of them, so I will end up creating only 10 instances of `DocumentBuilder`

Right now with JAXB I'm creating a new one per request, and the memory footprint it getting quite big under a lot of request.

Comment: Usually, the memory consumed by a `DocumentBuilder` is nothing compared to the document it is building.

Comment: good point, But I dont know why GC is not able clean up in time, and memory keep growing and growing

Comment: That would be a different question. But consider that with ten threads, you have ten documents in memory, then, when a thread abandons one document and starts building a new one, there only is the memory of one document reclaimable while the nine others might still be in use. So, at this point, a garbage collection would only reclaim 10% (of the memory occupied of all documents; in relation to the entire heap, the fraction might be even less).

Comment: yeah, but it seems JAXB consume a very important amount of memory for some Documents open, with 70 tps for a non very long xml we require 3gb of memory in 10 instances. So we're looking how to drastically reduce that memory. We're considering refactor the whole parser to VTD

Comment: DOM trees are very memory consuming in general. If you have chance to switch to a streaming approach like SAX parser, that would gain the most. Otherwise, an alternative parser might also gain something, but I don’t know, how much.